# How to beautify url in ADF

Tags: url, oracle-adf

I wonder if there are any way to beautify URL in ADF.
For example:
from

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/abc/faces/uglyurl?... to http://127.0.0.1:7001/abc/faces/nice-url
```

Comment: What version of JDeveloper do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the context root. 
The how to is explained very well on this blog: http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.be/2010/12/adf-changing-your-applications-url-or.html